# How to run fsharp test on Mac from terminal?

Tags: macos, f#, mono, nunit

I want to learn fsharp. So I'm looking at exercism.io

In their readme they instruct to use Xamarin Studio for running the test
http://exercism.io/languages/fsharp/tests

But I would like to just run the tests from the terminal. The exercises from exercism only include one F# file e.g. `HelloWorldTest.fs`.

This answer [Running tests on Mac OS X console using mono/nunit-console/4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828340/running-tests-on-mac-os-x-console-using-mono-nunit-console-4) instructs to run `nunit-console` with a `.csproj` or `.dll` file. But these files are not present in the exercism files. So I'm not clear what to do.

I have install mono using homebrew.
How do I run the NUnit test from the terminal in OSX?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running tests on Mac OS X console using mono/nunit-console/4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828340/running-tests-on-mac-os-x-console-using-mono-nunit-console-4)

Comment: Unfortunately that answer seems to be missing steps or doesn't apply to this particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this:

**1.** install dotnet as described https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos

**2.** In the folder of the exercise run

```
dotnet new --lang f#
```

**3.** Rename `Program.fs` to the name of the exercise e.g. `HelloWorld.fs`

**4.** Change `project.json` to

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "compilerName": "fsc",
    "compile": {
      "includeFiles": [
        "HelloWorld.fs",
        "HelloWorldTest.fs"
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "NUnit": "3.4.1",
    "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-beta-2"
  },
  "tools": {
    "dotnet-compile-fsc": "1.0.0-preview2-*"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8",
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.1"
        },
        "Microsoft.FSharp.Core.netcore": "1.0.0-alpha-160629"
      }
    }
  },
  "testRunner": "nunit"
}
```

This includes the `nunit` dependency.

Note `includeFiles`, this should include the source code file for the exercise and the test file. e.g. `HelloWorld.fs` and `HelloWorldTest.fs`

**5.** Install required packages by doing

```
dotnet restore
```

**6.** Add your code to the previously renamed source file e.g. `HelloWorld.fs`

**7.** Finallly, run test by doing

```
 dotnet test
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have to use [xbuild](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/xbuild/) on the command line to compile the fsproj file then the resulting dll can be executed with nunit on the commandline also.

If you don't have the fsproj you can use fsharpc on the file directly then call nunit, remembering to use mono to execute nunit.

`fsharpc HelloWorldTest.fs`

`mono nunit-console.exe HelloWorldTest.exe`

Sorry am not in a position to test this, but should be something like this.